# Linux pipe example . ipc pipe creation

Tags: linux, pipe, ipc

I was looking through the `pipe(2)` syscall example in linux, I got this from tldp: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html#SECTION00722000000000000000

When we need to close the input of child process we close fd(1) of child - fine, but we should also close the output of the parent i.e. close fd(0) of parent, why should we use else statement here, in this case the parent's fd(0) will close only when the fork fails, am I correct?

I feel there should not be `else` statement and both the input of child and output of parent should be closed for communication from child to parent correct?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't talk about child input and parent output, that looks like you are referring to `stdin` and `stdout`, which is not necessarily the same as the pipe's read and write channels.

For communication from child to parent, the child needs to close the pipe's read channel (`fd[0]` in your example), and the parent needs to close the pipe's write channel (`fd[1]`).

Your confusion seems to be more about forking than about pipes.

The `else` is needed, because we need to execute different code in the parent and in the child. It is very common to use `if` / `else` after forking to differentiate the code that executes in each process. Remember that `fork(2)` returns twice: in the parent, and in the newborn child. It returns the child's pid in the parent, and 0 in the child, so we use that to tell them apart.

In the example you posted, if `fork(2)` fails, the first `if` is entered and the process exits. Otherwise, a pair of `if` / `else` is used to execute different code in each process.